# Select the second instance of a string under quotation marks with regex

Tags: c++, regex

How can I select the second string under quotation marks with regular expressions?

For example:

```
entry = ("plk", "Kopiuj - linearnie");
entry = ("ptb", "Copiar - linear");
```

I know that `"[^"]*"` selects everything under quotation marks, but what I'd like to find with regex is "Kopiuj - linearnie" and "Copiar - linear" and ignore the first string under " like "plk" and "ptb" (i.e. the second string per line).

Cheers,

Comment: Is there always two strings in the list, or can there be more after the second?

Comment: Also, is it the actual regex you have problem with, or do you need help with what functions to call as well?

Comment: There can only be two strings in the list and I had problems with the regex itself not the functions to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it capture the closing parenthesis, like [so](http://regexr.com?31ms4)

```
"([^"]*)"\)
```

the resulting string is in the first capture group.

Comment: There's a problem related to your answer: it selects the last parenthesis as well, instead of just selecting what's under the quotation marks and the quotation themselves.

Comment: @jlo thats is why i said you need to only use first capture group and not the whole match.

Comment: Is it possible to select the first group when searching with regex in a text editor (f.i. notepad++)?

Comment: @jlo i don't know about notepad++, but generally you can access capture group `n` in replace pattern. For example regexr uses `$n` as you can see [here](http://regexr.com?31mtn)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, found a way around it by replacing it by a string that includes the removed parenthesis, e.g.:
    "Copy - mirror***"\)

Answer (score 1):

```
"[^"]*", *"([^"]*)"
```

Then access the first capture group.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
/"([^"]*)"[^"]*"([^"]*)"/
```

then the first string will be in the variable $1 and the second in $2 if you use a regex replace function.

Or you can do

```
/"[^"]*"$/
```

which will match at the end of the line (the $ character), so it only matches the last text.

http://www.regextester.com/index2.html is great for testing your regular expressions.